# How to Trigger a event when a http request failed?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to trigger a event whenever any http request i.e while loading css, js, results in anything other than 200.

Comment: u mean event when stylesheet  or external js added in current html ?

Comment: You could load the files dynamically through xmlhttp and redirect to another page (or do something different) when one of the loads fails (after n seconds or retries).

Comment: u can use - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: I am not using it for scrip load. I am using asynchronous push. So whenever the request fails i want to triger a event which  can reconnect